# how enable streaming music via the Google Assistant Service on Raspberry Pi 4 Python

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I have installed the Python Google Assistant Service SDK on my Raspberry pi4.
It's working fine however it won't stream either music or radio stations.

How do I implement this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use gassistpi on Raspberry pi 4 using Debian Buster.
I don't think its mensioned in the documentation but you will need to recompile the libraries to run using the default setup on Buster.

Also the project is no longer maintained by shivasiddharth. You will need to remove all references to uploader_id within the Python scripts for GAssistPi, youtube_dl and pafy. This is because Google has changed the JSON thats's returned by the YouTube Data API.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJpeP4s8qAAxUpUkEAHcbJBrkQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fshivasiddharth%2FGassistPi&usg=AOvVaw1QHWaqOxfmf1GznCYY6BoX&opi=89978449

https://gassistpi-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html